# How to use React Testing Library to test if the component updated by an useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, use-effect, react-testing-library

what I wish to test is when the user clicks the "XL" button, the products list is filtered, the component is updated, a new filtered product list will be displayed. the whole process follows those steps: user clicks the"XL" button->the handleSizeClick function is invoked->the "size=XL" is added to the search query-> an useEffect is monitoring the search query, once it finds there is size search query, it invokes the handleSearchQuery function to filter the products list and update the products list->the component updates, new products list is displayed.

My problem is, when I am writing test for this component, after I fire event from the "XL" button, the handleSizeClick and handleSearchQuery work fine, but component didn't update. I didn't get the result I expect.

Content.js

```
  const queryStr = useLocation().search;
  const queryObj = queryString.parse(queryStr);
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [productsList, setproductsList] = React.useState([]);
  //this is for storing the unfiltered products list
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(null);

  const handleSearchQuery = (products, query) => {
    const filteredProducts = products
      .map((product) => {
        if (searchObject(product, query)) {
          return product;
        }
      })
      .filter((item) => item !== undefined);
    return filteredProducts;
  };
  const handleSizeClick = (size) => {
    if (size === "all") {
      setproductsList(products.data);
      navigate(`${pathname}`);
      return;
    }
    //the url changes if the XL button is clicked
    //a search query will be added
    const newQueryObj = { ...queryObj, size };
    const newQueryStr = queryString.stringify(newQueryObj);
    navigate({ search: newQueryStr });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await httpService.get("/products");
        setProducts(data);
        setproductsList(data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  //we monitor if the url contains the size query
  //if it contains size query, we filter the products list
  useEffect(() => {
    if (products && queryObj.size) {
      setproductsList(handleSearchQuery(products.data, queryObj.size));
    }
  }, [products, queryObj.size]);

  return (
    <SectionWrapper className="content">
      <FilterWrapper>
        <ul>
          <li onClick={() => handleSizeClick("all")}>
            <FilterButton>all</FilterButton>
          </li>

          <li data-testid="XL" onClick={() => handleSizeClick("XL")}>
            <FilterButton>XL</FilterButton>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </FilterWrapper>
      <StyledResults className="productsList-counts">
        <span>{productsList.length > 0 ? productsList.length : 0}</span>{" "}
        {productsList.length > 1 ? "products" : "product"} found
      </StyledResults>
      <ContentWrapper>
        {productsList.map((product) => (
          <ProductCard product={product} key={product.id} />
        ))}
      </ContentWrapper>
    </SectionWrapper>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

Content.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Content from "./Content";
import httpService from "../../services/httpService";
import { productsList } from "../../mockData/productsList";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const mockData = [...productsList];
afterEach(cleanup);
jest.mock("../../services/httpService");

const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();
const mockUsedLocation = jest.fn();
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
  useLocation: () => mockUsedLocation
}));

const mockSelector = jest.fn();
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
jest.mock("react-redux", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-redux"),
  useSelector: () => mockSelector,
  useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
}));

const handleSizeClick = jest.fn();

//test if the content is rendered
describe("product should be render in Content component correctly", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    httpService.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockData));
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(window, "alert").mockImplementation(() => {});
    const setproductsList = jest.fn();
    const useStateMock = jest.fn(() => [productsList, setproductsList]);
    jest.spyOn(React, "useState").mockImplementation(useStateMock);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it("should render products at the content", async () => {
    const url = "/products";

    act(() => {
      render(<Content />);
    });
    expect(httpService.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(httpService.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);
    expect(screen.getByText("Sort by")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/found/g).textContent).toBe("10 products found");
  });
  it("the handleSizeClick is call when XL button is clicked", async () => {
    render(<Content />);

    const XLButton = screen.getByTestId("XL");
    XLButton.onclick = handleSizeClick.mockImplementation(() => {})("XL");
    expect(XLButton).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(XLButton);
    expect(handleSizeClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(handleSizeClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith("XL");
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      search: "size=XL"
    });
  });
  it("the prodcutsList is filtered when XL button is clicked", async () => {
    render(<Content />);

    const XLButton = screen.getByTestId("XL");
    XLButton.onclick = handleSizeClick.mockImplementation(() => {})("XL");

    fireEvent.click(XLButton);
    expect(screen.getByText(/found/g).textContent).toBe("5 products found");
  });
});
```

only the final test:"the prodcutsList is filtered when XL button is clicked" is failed, the result is:

> Expected: "5 products found"
> Received: "10 products found"

I've tried to use "act" "waitFor" 'rerender()", they all didn't work.
Can anyone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: The `handleSizeClick` function triggers a `navigate` call which you are mocking in your tests. You should have two tests: 1) check that `navigate` gets called with the right parameters when the `XL` button is clicked; 2) ensure the component gets rendered properly when the `XL` query string gets passed to it.

Comment: I see, so what I should do in the test "the prodcutsList is filtered when XL button is clicked" is mocking URL changes to test if the productslist is rendered correctly, and there is no need to simulate the XL button is clicked.  that is a solution. thanks. @juliomalves